# Symfony 2 : Flash message on login / logout

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony 2.6, I am looking for the best way to add a flash message on login  / logout in my application. I precise that in each case I don't want to modify the Response (I don't need to).

Here are my solutions :

**Login:**

**1. First solution :**

I can use the *[security.interactive_login](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/69b07e9c570fba6c4de9664571e15d70c42cbc0c/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/SecurityEvents.php)* event  or the *[security.authentication.success](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d94d837e9ea75d76eeb0a43e0535a5e7a7a01542/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/AuthenticationEvents.php)* event. In both case I can implement a listener to add a flash message when the event occurs.

**2. Second solution :**

I can create my own LoginSuccessHandler that implements the *AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface*, but in this case I have to return a response. Moreover, I am not familiar with this method and I am afraid to overwrite the default success handler. Is that correct ?

**Logout:**

I can create a LogoutListener that implements the *LogoutHandlerInterface*. In this case I am also afraid to overwrite the defaut logout handler.

Thank you for your proposals.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) login/logout logic etc. already implemented... 
Thereby you will have the possibilty to show errors on the login-check redirect:
To do this you must return the error to the twig

```
$session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Error message');
```

And in the twig you will need a block like this to show errors, if the session is holding any:

```
 {% block flashes %}
    {% if app.session.flashbag.peekAll|length > 0 %}
        {{ session_flash() }}
    {% endif %}
 {% endblock flashes %}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand your proposal. I effectively use the FOSUserBundle. There are actually seven predefined flash messages in this bundle depending on different events [(FlashListener.php)](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/FlashListener.php). Can you explain me where in the application you add a flash message ? My purpose is only to tell the user that he is now connected or deconnected. All flash messages are displayed in my layout.

Comment: You can add a service that hooks into the [FOSUser events](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/LastLoginListener.php) - add one that adds a flash after onImplicitLogin is successful and wherever the user goes, the flash message will appear after login.  There has to be one for logout but I'm not sure where in the docs it is.  You could hook into a [controller here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md) for the controllers that pass the events.

Comment: @George I have already created an additional listener that adds a flash message after successfull login (using security.interactive_login event but it should work using fos_user.security.implicit_login event). It works fine. I don't think a logout event exist. Even in symfony 2. I hook into the controllers as described in the documentation but for redirecting response.